# Changing binary to decimal using created constants (not parseINT() ) and declaring and initializing each of the 8 bits of the number

Tags: java

[Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFUEA.png)

I have been working on this forever now.  I am required to create Constants then declare and initiate each then multiplying each by it's place value (128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1)

I know Integer.parseINT(Binary....) would do the job quickly however I CANNOT USE IT.

followed is what i have thus far, am i even on the right track?  I know i need to get each of the separated user input values and have them multiplied by their place values then added to create the decimal but i for the life of me cannot figure out how to do it through for loop or defining each variable

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Integer;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class Binary
{

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Binary Number Please");
    Integer[] digits = getDigits(keyboard.nextInt());



    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));

}//End bracket method main

    public static Integer[] getDigits(int num)
    {
        List <Integer> digits = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        collectDigits(num, digits);
        return digits.toArray(new Integer[]{});

    }//end bracket method Integer

    private static void collectDigits(int num, List <Integer> digits)
    {

       if(num / 10 > 0)
       {
            collectDigits(num / 10, digits);

        }//End method collectDigits

        digits.add(num % 10);

    }

}
```

I am wanting to separate each character of the user input binary so i can have them multiplied by their place value, then each product added to create the sum that will then be displayed to the user via `System.out.println()`

Comment: Post the error that you get. Furthermore, why are you declaring the "keyboard" variable, and asking for a number, if you are not getting the input from the user?

Comment: I am asking the user to input a binary number (i.e User input (11011) and am wanting the program to output the decimal value

Comment: @Vincente Freire - 
Type list does not take parameters
'private static void collectDigits (int num, List<Integer> digits);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing the wrong List type. Change this line:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

To:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Comment: This fixed the List<Integer> error thank you, now to figure how to declare and initialize each variable of the input

Comment: Successive calls to keyboard.nextInt() should let you type the inputs.

Comment: How do I take the inputed numbers to separate them so as to multiply them by their place value?

Comment: With a for loop you can make calls to keyboard.nextInt() and store the result into each position of the array.

Comment: how do i call on the Array to pull each individual digit to create a loop?